# actualizar hook, desde un useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de actualizar el *hook*

```
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(hotelsData);
```

El estado inicial es **hotetsData** que es un array de objetos con información de hoteles, cuando lo envío como *prop* al componente *card*

```
<HotelCard hotelsData={filteredList}/>
```

recorro el array y muestra la información.

*filterValues* es un objeto cuyos valores se actualizan desde otro componente (`useContext`)

```
country: "uruguay"
dateFrom: ""
dateTo: ""
large: ""
price: ""
```

Quiero filtar la información mediante un `filter` donde coincida el country del estado inicial con el country de filter values

```
const filterByCountry = filteredList.filter(function(country){
                return country.country === filterValues.country;
            });
```

con el console veo que me trae un array filtrado que se lo quiero asignar al estado

```
setFilteredList(filterByCountry)
```

Pero siempre me envía un array vacio, y no se porque, quiero actualizar el estado con la nueva lista filtrada para hacer otros filtros sobre ella.

Como podría actualizar el estado dentro del `useEffect` ?

Gracias por la ayuda

```
 import React, {useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react';
    import Container from '../elements/Container';
    import  HotelCard from './HotelCard';
    import {FilterContext} from '../states/FilterContext';
    import {hotelsData} from '../data';
    
    
    function Results() {
         //context
         const {filterValues} = useContext(FilterContext);
        console.log(filterValues);
    
         const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(hotelsData);
     
         useEffect(()=>{
            const filterByCountry = filteredList.filter(function(country){
                return country.country === filterValues.country;
            });
    
            if(filterByCountry){
                setFilteredList(filterByCountry);
                console.log(filterByCountry);
                
            }
            
        },[filterValues.country]);
        
    
         //Muestra un array vacio
         console.log(filteredList);
    
    
        
        return (
            <div>
                <Container>
                    <h1>Resultados</h1>
                </Container>
                <Container d_flex wrap="true">
                    <HotelCard hotelsData={filteredList}/>
                </Container>    
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Results
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado te muestra *console.log(filterByCountry);*? Si es la lista filtrada entonces *setFilteredList(filterByCountry)* debería funcionar  para actualizar a *filteredList* en el useEffect

Comment: Hola, console.log(filterByCountry) si muestra la lista filtrada pero console.log(filteredList) me muestra un array vacio

Comment: Entonces  *setFilteredList(filterByCountry)* esta asignando el valor correcto a *filteredList*, lo único que se me ocurre es usar la función en el setter  setFilteredList((prevValue) => { console.log(prevValue) return filterByCountry } solamente para verificar que el valor asignado es el de *filterByCountry*